# iterating through an array of dataframes in pandas and plotting column values

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have an array of dataframes: `myArr=[df1,df2,df3]`  Each of those dataframes have 3 columns that I would like to plot in a loop.

```
colName = ['name1','name2','name3']
df_collection = [df1,df2,df3]
traces =[]
for x in range(2):
  traces.append(
       go.Scatter(
           x=df_collection[x],
           y=df_collection[x][colName[x]],
       )
     )

fig = go.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)
py.offline.iplot(fig)
```

I get

> TypeError: Object of type 'DataFrame' is not JSON serializable

Comment: I assume `plotly` requires json-serializable objects. Try `data.to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody else is having the same issue.  The problem was the values in the x-axis need to be `x=df_collection[x].index.values`.